# How can we simplify this product of arc-cos equation?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Given a product formula: $\arccos(f_1(x))*\arccos(f_2(y))=\arccos(f_3(x))*\arccos(f_4(y))$

where $f_1(x), f_2(y), f_3(x), f_4(y)$ are linear functions over $x$ and $y$ with rational coefficients and constants.

Can we simplify the relation b/w $f_1(x), f_2(y), f_3(x), f_4(y)$ without using product of $\arccos()$ or trigonometric terms as above? Couldn't find much.

Comment: can someone please help?

Comment: For context, do you know any non-trivial example of such a product formula?